# How to use custom ingest pipelines with docker autodiscover

Tags: docker, elastic-stack, filebeat

I'm having a hard time using custom Elasticsearch ingest pipelines with Filebeat's Docker autodiscovery. I've started out with custom processors in my `filebeat.yml` file, however I would prefer to shift this to custom ingest pipelines I've created.

Firstly, here is my configuration using custom processors that works to provide custom grok-like processing for my [Servarr](https://wiki.servarr.com/) app Docker containers (identified by applying a label to them in my docker-compose.yml file). The processor copies the 'message' field to 'log.original', uses dissect to extract 'log.level', 'log.logger' and overwrite 'message'. The final processor is a JavaScript function used to convert the log.level to lowercase (overkill perhaps, but humour me).

Filebeat configuration:

```
filebeat.config:
  modules:
    path: ${path.config}/modules.d/*.yml
    reload.enabled: true
    reload.period: 60s

filebeat.autodiscover:
  providers:
    - type: docker
      hints.enabled: true
      json.keys_under_root: true

processors:
  - if:
      equals:
        docker.container.labels.co_elastic_logs/custom_processor: servarr
    then:
      - copy_fields:
          fields:
            - from: message
              to: log.original
          fail_on_error: false
          ignore_missing: true
      - dissect:
          tokenizer: "[%{log.level}] %{log.logger}: %{message}"
          field: message
          target_prefix: ""
          overwrite_keys: true
          ignore_failure: true
      - script:
          lang: javascript
          id: lowercase
          source: >
            function process(event) {
                var level = event.Get("log.level");
                if(level != null) {
                    event.Put("log.level", level.toString().toLowerCase());
                }
            }

output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: 'elasticsearch:9200'
  username: 'elastic'
  password: '*************'

setup.kibana.host: 'kibana:5601'

logging.json: true
logging.metrics.enabled: false
```

Excerpt from docker-compose.yml file...

```
  lidarr:
    image: ghcr.io/linuxserver/lidarr:latest
    container_name: lidarr
    labels:
      co.elastic.logs/custom_processor: "servarr"
```

And an example log line (in json):

```
{"log":"[Info] DownloadDecisionMaker: Processing 100 releases \n","stream":"stdout","time":"2021-08-07T10:10:49.125702754Z"}
```

This works well, and achieves my aims of extracting fields, but ideally I'd like to use Elasticsearch's (more powerful) ingest pipelines instead, and live with a cleaner `filebeat.yml`, so I created a working ingest pipeline "filebeat-7.13.4-servarr-stdout-pipeline" like so (ignore the fact that for now, this only does the grokking):

```
[
  {
    "grok": {
      "field": "message",
      "patterns": [
        "\\[%{LOGLEVEL:log.level}\\] %{WORD:log.logger}: %{GREEDYDATA:message}"
      ],
      "trace_match": true,
      "ignore_missing": true
    }
  }
]
```

I tested the pipeline against existing documents (not ones that have had my custom processing applied, I should note). The pipeline worked against all the documents I tested it against in the Kibana interface.

So now I come to shift my Filebeat config to use this pipeline for containers with my custom_processor label. This is the `filebeat.yml` I came up with, which is apparently valid and works for the most part, but doesn't apply the grokking:

```
filebeat.config:
  modules:
    path: ${path.config}/modules.d/*.yml
    reload.enabled: true
    reload.period: 60s

filebeat.autodiscover:
  providers:
    - type: docker
      hints.enabled: true
      json.keys_under_root: true
      appenders:
        - type: config
          condition.equals:
            docker.container.labels.co_elastic_logs/custom_processor: servarr
          config:
            pipeline: filebeat-7.13.4-servarr-stdout-pipeline

output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: 'elasticsearch:9200'
  username: 'elastic'
  password: '*************'

setup.kibana.host: 'kibana:5601'

logging.json: true
logging.metrics.enabled: false
```

If I use Filebeat's inbuilt modules for my other containers such as nginx, by using a label such as in this example below, the inbuild module pipelines are used:

```
  nginx-repo:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: nginx-repo
    mem_limit: 2048m
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=repo.***.***.***,repo
      - VIRTUAL_PORT=80
      - HTTPS_METHOD=noredirect
    networks:
      - default
      - proxy
    labels:
      co.elastic.logs/module: "nginx"
      co.elastic.logs/fileset.stdout: "access"
      co.elastic.logs/fileset.stderr: "error"
```

What am I doing wrong here? The logs still end up in Elasticsearch and Kibana, and are processed, but my grok isn't applied, new fields aren't created, and the 'message' field is unchanged.

EDIT: In response to one of the comments linking to a post on the elastic forums, which suggested both the path(s) and the pipeline need to be made explicit, I tried the following `filebeat.yml` autodiscovery excerpt, which also fails to work (but is apparently valid config):

```
filebeat.autodiscover:
  providers:
    - type: docker
      hints.enabled: true
      json.keys_under_root: true
      appenders:
        - type: config
          condition:
            equals:
              docker.container.labels.co_elastic_logs/custom_processor: "servarr"
          config:
            - type: docker
              containers:
                ids:
                  - "${data.docker.container.id}"
                stream: all
              paths:
                - /var/lib/docker/containers/${data.docker.container.id}/${data.docker.container.id}-json.log
              pipeline: filebeat-7.13.4-servarr-stdout-pipeline
```

I tried with the `docker.container.labels.co_elastic_logs/custom_processor` value both quoted and unquoted. I have the same behaviour where the logs end up in Elasticsearch / Kibana, but they are processed as if they skipped my ingest pipeline.

Comment: Use [Logstash](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/index.html) to achieve the GROK filtering. Let Filebeat to forward the logs to Logstash for processing and in the output of Logstash you can have Elasticsearch.

Logstash is rich with many different plugins to use and is very convenient.

Comment: Please check https://discuss.elastic.co/t/filebeat-and-grok-parsing-errors/143371/2

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using Logstash where possible due to the extra resources and extra point of failure + complexity. My understanding is that what I am trying to achieve should be possible without Logstash, and as I've shown, is possible with custom processors. I just want to move the logic into ingest pipelines.

Perhaps I just need to also add the file paths in regard to your other comment, but my assumption was they'd "carry over" from autodiscovery. I will try adding the path to the log file explicitly in addition to specifying the pipeline. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

We're using Kubernetes instead of Docker with Filebeat but maybe our config might still help you out.

We have autodiscover enabled and have all pod logs sent to a common ingest pipeline *except* for logs from any Redis pod which use the Redis module and send their logs to Elasticsearch via one of two custom ingest pipelines depending on whether they're normal Redis logs or slowlog Redis logs, this is configured in the following block:

[image]

All other detected pod logs get sent in to a common ingest pipeline using the following catch-all configuration in the "output" section:

[image]

Something else that we do is add the name of the ingest pipeline to ingested documents using the "set" processor:

[image]

This has proven to be really helpful when diagnosing whether or not a pipeline was actually executed when viewing an event document in Kibana.

Comment: what is the value of `${data.kubernetes.container.id}`? Can you please share an example?

Comment: @Moulick that's a built-in reference used by Filebeat autodiscover. It doesn't have a value.